# AngularJS - Acessar uma variável de um serviço

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como faço para acessar a variável `LatLng` na aplicação?

```
$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: './database/getCep.php'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
       var LatLng = $scope.get_cep = response.data;
       console.log(LatLng);
});
```

Comment: Provavel que você precisará colocar ela no escopo, mas mostrenos o que deseja fazer de maneira mais clara.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, para você acessar essa variável terá que passar pela função do then.
Seria interessante criar uma função para acessá-la, como um getLatLng().

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
$http({
       method: 'POST',
       url: './database/getCep.php'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
       var LatLng = $scope.get_cep = response.data;
       return LatLng;
});
```